# Filter from string in the param that comes from another parameter in memory - XSLT

Tags: xslt

I need some tip here.

I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A_Product>
   <A_ProductType>
      <to_Description>
         <A_ProductDescriptionType>
            <Language>DE</Language>
            <ProductDescription>Handelsware 14, PD, Zukauf, H14</ProductDescription>
         </A_ProductDescriptionType>
         <A_ProductDescriptionType>
            <Language>EN</Language>
            <ProductDescription>Trad.Good 14,PD,Bought-In,H14</ProductDescription>
         </A_ProductDescriptionType>
         <A_ProductDescriptionType>
            <Language>PT</Language>
            <ProductDescription>TESTE OPERADOR WMS 2021</ProductDescription>
         </A_ProductDescriptionType>
         <A_ProductDescriptionType>
            <Language>ES</Language>
            <ProductDescription>Mercadería 14, PD, comprado, H14</ProductDescription>
         </A_ProductDescriptionType>
      </to_Description>
      <to_Plant>
         <A_ProductPlantType>
            <Plant>M016</Plant>
            <SerialNumberProfile>0001</SerialNumberProfile>
         </A_ProductPlantType>
         <A_ProductPlantType>
            <Plant>S039</Plant>
            <SerialNumberProfile>0001</SerialNumberProfile>
         </A_ProductPlantType>
         <A_ProductPlantType>
            <Plant>T161</Plant>
            <SerialNumberProfile>0001</SerialNumberProfile>
         </A_ProductPlantType>
         <A_ProductPlantType>
            <Plant>T191</Plant>
            <SerialNumberProfile>0001</SerialNumberProfile>
         </A_ProductPlantType>
      </to_Plant>
   </A_ProductType>
</A_Product>
```

I'm doing already the filter based on language 'PT' but also I need exclude all <A_ProductPlantType>  that is different of value from PARAM array.

How to make it ?

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
 <xsl:output method="xml"  omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
 <xsl:param name="Centros" select="T191,M016"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="//A_ProductDescriptionType[Language!='PT']"/>
  <xsl:template match="//A_ProductPlantType[Plant!=$Centros]"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

Current result, exclude all from <to_Plant> and this is not correct, should return the values contain in the PARAM, in this case:

```
<to_Plant>
         <A_ProductPlantType>
            <Plant>M016</Plant>
            <SerialNumberProfile>0001</SerialNumberProfile>
         </A_ProductPlantType>
         <A_ProductPlantType>
            <Plant>T191</Plant>
            <SerialNumberProfile>0001</SerialNumberProfile>
         </A_ProductPlantType>
</to_Plant>
```

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using? This could be easier if it supports tokenizing as an extension function.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could do it this way :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
 <xsl:output method="xml"  omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
 <xsl:param name="Centros" select="'T191,M016'"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="A_ProductDescriptionType[Language!='PT']"/>
  <xsl:template match="A_ProductPlantType[not(contains($Centros,Plant))]"/>
  
</xsl:transform>
```

You need to add single quotes to your "Centros" string.

Also I would advise that you declare your string something like this : "'|T191|,|M016|'" in order to avoid substrings of your codes being taken into account.

Then change your template to:

```
<xsl:template match="A_ProductPlantType[not(contains($Centros,concat('|',Plant,'|'))]"/>
```

Comment: This is an error in XSLT 1.0 and an overcomplication in XSLT 2.0.

Comment: This is works because the param Centros comes from variable in memory not as declarate as string with select. Really thanks.

Comment: @DeveloperXSLT This does NOT work if you're using a conforming XSLT 1.0 processor.

Answer (score 0):

You have several mistakes, among them having a `param` that contains a reference   instead of a string. Also, in XSLT 1.0 you cannot use a variable or a param in a match pattern.

Try it along these lines:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="Centros">T191,M016</xsl:param>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="A_ProductDescriptionType[Language!='PT']"/>

<xsl:template match="A_ProductPlantType">
    <xsl:if test="contains(concat(',', $Centros, ','), concat(',', Plant, ','))">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for replay, this is works testing only, but the values of Centros, comes from memory and not works this solution proper with the integraiton platform. Really great 1

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand what "comes from memory" means. The value of `xsl:param` is either the value that is passed by the calling application or the default value hard-coded into the stylesheet. If you're passing a comma-separated string, then the above will work. If you're passing a node-set, then a simple comparison will suffice.

Comment: The param comes from another parameter save in memory extract from JSON input file.

Comment: Sorry, that makes no sense to me.

Comment: Instead of - <xsl:param name="Centros">T191,M016</xsl:param> will be only <xsl:param name="Centros"> and the value inside Centros = T191,M016.

Comment: That would be a comma-separated string - and everything I said above still applies. If you're not getting the expected result using my answer, then something is different from what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT-2.0 you could make use of a sequence for the param match:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
 <xsl:output method="xml"  omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
 <xsl:param name="Centros" select="('T191','M016')"/>    <!-- Sequence -->
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="to_Description//A_ProductDescriptionType[Language!='PT']"/>
  <xsl:template match="to_Plant//A_ProductPlantType[Plant=$Centros]"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

But in XSLT-1.0, this is more complicated, because

> Variable references in match patterns are not allowed by XSLT 1.0, but they are allowed in XSLT 2.0

So you have to invert the logic like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
 <xsl:output method="xml"  omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
 <xsl:param name="Centros1" select="'T191'"/>   <!-- One value per parameter -->
 <xsl:param name="Centros2" select="'M016'"/>   <!-- One value per parameter -->
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
 
 <xsl:template match="to_Description//A_ProductDescriptionType[Language!='PT']"/>

  <xsl:template match="to_Plant//A_ProductPlantType">
    <xsl:if test="Plant!=$Centros1 and Plant!=$Centros2"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" /></xsl:copy></xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

The output in both cases should be the same:

```
<A_Product>
    <A_ProductType>
        <to_Description>
            <A_ProductDescriptionType>
                <Language>PT</Language>
                <ProductDescription>TESTE OPERADOR WMS 2021</ProductDescription>
            </A_ProductDescriptionType>
        </to_Description>
        <to_Plant>
            <A_ProductPlantType>
                <Plant>S039</Plant>
                <SerialNumberProfile>0001</SerialNumberProfile>
            </A_ProductPlantType>
            <A_ProductPlantType>
                <Plant>T161</Plant>
                <SerialNumberProfile>0001</SerialNumberProfile>
            </A_ProductPlantType>
        </to_Plant>
    </A_ProductType>
</A_Product>
```

If you want to pass several strings as parameters delimited by commas, you could create an `xsl:for-each` loop iterating over each substring - which would be quite complicated.

Comment: In XSLT 2.0 you could simply tokenize the param as given (and with some XSLT 1.0 processors you could do the same).

Comment: Thank you very much for the replay.

Comment: Note that *some* XSLT 1.0 processors allow you to use global variables (and parameters) in match patterns, even though the spec explicitly says it's an error.